# Is there a way to run preload in electron on a new window opened from renderer

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I am working on electron app that will be wrapper around my web based app. I want to enable my user to expand their view and by clicking on a button to open a new window. Window is opened from a web using `window.open(...)` and it all goes well, it responds well to all movement and other params. My main window in electron has a preload file that exposes in main world (browser `window`) `application` that has its own fields that are used by the web when running over electron application. However, I have noticed that newly created window does not have `window.application` and that my preload script has not been run. I have gone through bunch of github PRs and issues and I have read (tried stuff from) electron documentation but I am unable to make it run. Is there a way to run preload script in newly created window from renderer process?

I have tried adding

```
    action: ActionType.Allow,
    overrideBrowserWindowOptions: {
      fullscreen: isFullscreenEnabled(details),
      webPreferences: {
        devTools: true,
        nodeIntegration: true,
        nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: true,
        preload: '/absolute/path/to/preload.ts',
      },
```

into `webContents.setWindowOpenHandler` but it did not work.

I have tried with passing the `nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: true,` in features part of `window.open` in renderer call.
I have also tried the same with running `new BrowserWindow(...)` and `nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: true,` as one of webPreferences but nothing worked.

Comment: Register a JS `click` event handler on the button and when clicked, IPC from the render process to the main process to open a new window (similar to your main window), which also includes reference to your `preload.js` script.